# spark: how to zip an RDD with each partition of the other RDD

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Let's say I have one `RDD[U]` that will always consist of only 1 partition. My task is fill this RDD up with the contents of another `RDD[T]` that resides over *n* number of partitions. The final output should be *n* number of partitions of `RDD[U]`.

What I tried to do originally is:

```
val newRDD = firstRDD.zip(secondRDD).map{ case(a, b)  => a.insert(b)}
```

But I got an error: `Can't zip RDDs with unequal numbers of partitions`

I can see in the RDD api [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) that there is a method called `zipPartitions()`. Is it possible, and if so how, to use this method to zip each partition from `RDD[T]` with a single and only partition of `RDD[U]` and perform a map on it as I tried above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
val zippedFirstRDD = firstRDD.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
val zippedSecondRDD = secondRDD.zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)

zippedFirstRDD.join(zippedSecondRDD)
  .map{case (key, (valueU, valueT)) => {
    valueU.insert(valueT)
  }}
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I asked the question incorrectly because I didn't realize the zip fnc combines elements from two RRDs that have the same keys - even thought this is not I was looking for, it works/answers the question I posted.